# File Upload Error 413 - Concrete5

Tags: php, file, upload, concrete5

I am using a CMS called concrete5. When i try uploading files, using the appropriate file upload box, I get a 413 error. Now small files with small sizes seem to upload. A very strange thing I noticed was, that an image with a small file size but massive resolution will not upload. PDFs will small size and larger resolution do not upload as well. My problem is I cannot upload most of my PDFs and images. I can resize images but I cannot resize PDFs.

When I try uplaoding multiple files I get a Server (IO) Error.

Here is what I know:

1. I first updated the php.ini to accept larger files by changing the
   max_post_size and upload_max_filesize.
2. I also increase the memory_limit.
3. I created a demo website on http://www.concrete5.org/ to check if it is a concrete5 issue or my server. The same files that DO NOT upload on my website, DO UPLOAD on the demo website.
4. This leads me to believe it is a server issue and not a PHP issue (since I changed the php.ini file)
5. If I just use FileZilla i can upload these large files to my server.

So to sum up, I am extremely confused to why this is not working. I have created a thread in the concrete5 forums. Here is the link:http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/file-upload-help/#584250

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Both Apache and php might be limiting how much data you can upload through an http request (different from ftp)

You already made changes to your PHP.ini but I have to point out that it is **not max_post_size** but **post_max_size** that should be used.

On the other hand, Apache has a LimitRequestBody directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)
That directive allows to set a limit to the size of http requests.

Of course if you are on a shared server you might have problems controlling that but it's worth asking your host about it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for your reply. I am sorry, I have changed the post_max_size. I typed the wrong thing there. I will take a look into this.

Comment: I have tried changing the LimitRequestBody in the .htaccess. By adding this line: LimitRequestBody 2147483647
This has not worked for me. Really stressing since I have a couple client sites using this and it just does not work. Its definitely not a fault with concrete5 because I tried using the demo site that you can setup on concrete5.org and it does work properly. But it's not working on my server :-(